LWC Injecting HTML
I'm simply trying to use the lwc:inner-html example provided in the link below and can't get around the compile error:

LWC1534: lwc:inner-html attribute is not supported.

https://lwc.dev/guide/html_templates#inject-raw-html-content
I can't find this lwc:inner-hmtl directive in the official SF LWC docs, maybe its not officially supported? I'm supposed to use lwc:dom="manual"?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-directives.html
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-directives.html#lwccolondommanual

LWR (from lwc.dev) is not the same as LWC in Salesforce. If you're developing in Salesforce, use the LWC documentation, and if you're building a standalone app (e.g. for Heroku), use the lwc.dev guide. In this case, you should use lwc:dom="manual" if you want to control the DOM inside a node. Note that sanitation still occurs when you use this directive, so it's not possible to inject scripts and other unsafe content.
